# creating records in web2py after migration to postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, web2py

I have moved my database from SQlite to postgresql. The problem I have is that when I try to create any table, it does not return any notice and refreshes the page and does not create the record. I have some tables and none of them create a record. I am creating the records using admin page on the website just like I did with SQLite. I read it is the same way with postgresql.

Answer (score 0):

Have you confirmed that the username and password are correct? It seems like a permissions issue to me. You can use the [command line](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-cheat-sheet/) or webmin if you have it to verify this info.

Comment: I can create records in the interface of the postgresql and they show up in the web2py database admin. But with SQLlite I could create records on the web2py's admin page. I am not sure if that means that with postgresql it is no longer possible to create records with web2py's admin.

Comment: The other problem is that the user that I create in postresql's interface and shows up in the web2py's database, cannot login to the app. I have made sure the credentials are correct.

Comment: You can definitely use the admin console of web2py to create records. It just seems like a permissions issue to me. I would double-check the user account you are using in web2py  in the line DAL('postgres://user_name:user_password@server_addr/db_name') has INSERT and UPDATE permissions.  You can modify those permissions from the command line with GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT ON mytable TO admin;